# Enabling antialiasing in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps, directx-11

I have a D3D11 application for Windows Store that currently does not use antialiasing, and I would like to enable it.

According to MSDN, [MSAA is disabled in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173077.aspx#DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL):

> **DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL**
>   Use this flag to specify the flip presentation model and to specify that DXGI persist the contents of the back buffer after you call IDXGISwapChain1::Present1. This flag cannot be used with multisampling.
>   **Note**  Windows Store apps must use DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL.

Because this limitation applies only to the back buffer, it sounds like the best workaround is to create a new off-screen render target, enable MSAA on that, render everything to it, and immediately before Present, blit the off-screen target to the back buffer (probably with [ResolveSubresource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

I've started implementing this, but I'm not sure how to modify my swap chain and render target view. Can anybody advise me as to the correct order of operations here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you suggest is correct.  Create an MSAA render target using CreateTexture2D followed by CreateRenderTargetView.  The DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC field of D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC contains the MSAA settings.  Then render your scene to this render target, and ResolveSubresource into the back buffer.  The swap chain doesn't need to change.

Comment: Note this is covered in a bit more detail on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681697.aspx). It says "Windows phone 8", but it applies to Windows Store, Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps, Xbox One, and Direct3D 12--these cases all require the 'flip' style DXGI swap effect ``DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL`` or ``DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD`` which do not support the  'implicit resolve' behavior of the older 'bitblit' style swap effects (``DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD`` or ``DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_SEQUENTIAL``)